# Let $F$ be an intersecting family of $m$ subsets of $[n]$, then the elements of $F$ have at least $2m$ subsets.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $F$ be a subset of $2^{[n]}$ such that any two (possibly equal) elements of $F$ intersect. We define $W=\bigcup\limits_{f\in F} 2^f$. In other words all elements in $2^{[n]}$ that are a subset of some element in $F$. I think that it is true that $|W|\geq 2|F|$, but I have not been able to prove it.

Comment: This question has been answered at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268433/for-an-intersecting-family-of-m-sets-there-are-at-least-2m-sets-that-are-con) with a proof of the conjectured result